# Overlay a blur effect but still have text highlightable

Tags: html, css, overlay, blur, overlap

So I have two elements inside of my webisite. What I want to do is have a blur effect on the page and overlapping my text, but only the outside. I want the text to still be editable, highlightable, and whatnot. At the moment I have two classes, a main class where the text goes in, and a overlay class that should overlap the main class.

```
.main{
    top:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.1in;
    background-color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.50);
    z-index:0;
}

.overlay{
    opacity:0.8;
    filter: blur(0.1in);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0.1in);
    -moz-filter: blur(0.1in);
    -ms-filter: blur(0.1in);
    -o-filter: blur(0.1in);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xyphqvoo/)

Comment: Please share a useful code example, e. g. at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: [Do you mean like this](http://jsfiddle.net/xyphqvoo/)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you're having? To me the text looks editable and highlightable.

Comment: What I want to do is have the blur effect that's being applied to the background element overlap the main element. Because as it is right now, the main element overlaps the blur and for asthetic reasons, I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution for you:

Remember to mark whatever you are trying to show clearly, as a sibling to .overlay.

```
.main:hover .overlay{ /*filtering stuff*/}
```

**Upadeted CodePen**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpQoqP

Any better?

Comment: What I want to do is to have the main element to be covered by the blur that is effecting the background element.

Comment: Just to clarify, but what I mean is that the background has its blur effect. And the main element doesn't, but what I want is that when I'm scrolling, the main doesn't overlap the blur but it goes under it, and isn't obstructed at all, I.e. it's still highlightable. Sorry if this is asking too much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can make your text editable.

Don't use p tag for this. Use textarea and apply some CSS codes like this fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/xyphqvoo/2/

I replaced your p tag code with textarea. Below is the CSS which did the trick of editable text.

```
 .editable {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

There you can get the editable text of your first paragraph.

Note : To tweak about the textarea, check out this awesome article.

https://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/